# How to activate 2016 Standard guest VMs on a 2016 Standard (not Datacenter) server?

Tags: windows-server-2016, activation

I understand that AVMA activation only works with a Datacenter edition host machine. However, the Standard edition is supposed to allow 2 VM installs of Standard as well, but how should those VMs be activated without AVMA?

Comment: Put in the product key and activate them manually?

Comment: I should have specified that the hosts are KMS-activated from the hosting service, and I was not given a key to use.

Comment: Yes, that would have been helpful. Then you use [Active Directory-Based Activation](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2013/02/04/active-directory-based-activation-vs-key-management-services/).

Comment: We aren't using an AD on this setup, the VMs are standalone. Am I supposed to use slmgr to set the VMs to use the hosting service's KMS server? Also, the AD activation option still requires a key, which I don't have.

Comment: You don't have the host's product key? You should definitely find that before going any further.

Answer (score 1):

Just use same product key, what was used for physical server. I just did activation for two VM (Server 2019), running on Server 2019 Standard. Just enter yours OEM product key (from label) in VM (change product key, activate) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `nslookup -type=srv _vlmcs._tcp` to make sure there's a DNS record for your KMS host server.

Then use `slmgr.vbs /ipk WC2BQ-8NRM3-FDDYY-2BFGV-KHKQY` to activate.

I found the KMS Client Setup Key here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/jj612867(v=ws.11)

Comment: That seems like the command I would use to activate the VM host, but it is already activated. Could you clarify that this should also activate the VM guests as well? Also, I ran the nslookup and got no results, but the output of slmgr /dlv on the VM host gives me the KMS server name and port. I could use that for the VM guests?